# How to convert laravel query to sql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.8

Laravel query is given below, can you explain with how is it working?

```
Business::orderby('name')
                ->with(['subscriptions' => function ($query) use ($date_today) {
                    $query->whereDate('start_date', '<=', $date_today)
                        ->whereDate('end_date', '>=', $date_today);
                }, 'locations', 'owner'])
                ->paginate(21);
```

This is Laravel query and I want to convert it into a normal query? How to do so if I want to join one more table to `Business` model?

Comment: use `toSql()` to print mysql query

Comment: do `->toSql()` in place of `->paginate(21)`

Comment: it is not generating, only I get  
```
select * from `business` order by `name` asc

```

Comment: That query is what you'd expect from the code you shared. `with` queries are performed separately from the main query. You need to share more details on what you're trying to achieve because I suspect that there's either a better way to do it without needing the raw query

Comment: try to put some error on table name, error will be shown there with whole query.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your requirements are unclear from the question.

You need to understand the Laravel [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries) and [Relations eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) in terms of understanding what the above query is doing and how to do the [joins](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins) in laravel query.

The above query is querying the `Business` Model, by `eager loading` the relations - `subscriptions`, `owner` and `locations` in one query. Also rather than getting all subscriptions it also filter the relation based on `$date_today`.

If you want to do the join to other model, then you can use the laravel joins . Then you query will become:

```
Business::orderby('name')->with(['subscriptions' => function ($query) use ($date_today) {
                    $query->whereDate('start_date', '<=', $date_today)
                        ->whereDate('end_date', '>=', $date_today);
                }, 'locations', 'owner'])
                ->joins(JOIN QUERY)->paginate(21);
```

Make sure to replace the JOIN QUERY with your required logic.